# Objective C: Problem in switching BOOLEAN value of property after button press

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I am trying to switch the BOOLEAN value of the property 'isLiked' as seen in the code below

```
//BOOL isLiked is defined in the header file as property of answer class
- (void)buttonPressed
{
    NSLog(@"button pressed");

    if ([btnType isEqualToString:@"like"]) 
    {
       self.answer.isLiked = !self.answer.isLiked;  
       NSLog(@"answer is: %i",self.answer.isLiked);
   }

}
```

When I print out the value of 'self.answer.isLiked' I see that the value returned is always '0'. How can I switch the values??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing `self.answer` is, in fact, nil. That will cause `self.answer.isLiked = !self.answer.isLiked` to do nothing at all, and will cause your NSLog to actually be logging the integer value of nil, which is 0.

Comment: you are absolutely right about the fact that my self.answer is nil. I fixed that it is now working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your header looks kinda like:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isLiked) BOOL liked;
```

In which case, your button press code needs to be:

```
self.answer.liked = !self.answer.isLiked;
NSLog(@"answer is: %i",self.answer.isLiked);
```

Note the setter for your boolean drops the 'is' prefix, and makes the first letter lowercase.

Comment: Depends on the compiler settings. I tested it before I posted with 4.0.2 on a new project, it compiled fine but just didn't work.

Comment: The compiler should be warning about calling a method that it doesn't know about (setIsLiked:), and it should trigger an exception at runtime.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: Hm, that leads me to worry about the sanity of my machine. It has XCode 3, 4.0.2, and 4.2 all installed. I was hoping that leaving the unix tools unchecked during the 4.2 install was sufficient, but it sounds like I've built a frankencompiler I can't trust. Thanks for the feedback though.